How can I convert a TFJS model to TFLite?
I'm attempting to convert a TFJS model which consists of a model.json and group1-shard1 - 7 files.
I'm trying to load the model in tfjs like this:
import tfjs_graph_converter.api as tfjs
tfjs.graph_model_to_saved_model('model.json', "savedmodel")

However, this returns an error:
ModelFormatError: unsupported model format: ''

I'm not really sure where to go from here. How can I get the model to load so I can save a TFJS saved model?
I would expect the model to load and export to the savedmodel directory.
